# How to Sum two columns meeting certain conditions

Tags: sum, sql-like

What I want to do is basically merge the two highlighted code, so that the end result is it using this SUM formula for only the items matching the LIKE criteria (under WHERE) - so that I am still able to pull GameDescriptions that do not include the LIKE criteria. Hope that makes sense... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IURi9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to replace that part of the WHERE statement with a case statement in the SUM, like this:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN GameDescription LIKE '5R25L%' THEN NetRevenue 
    ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT AccountingDate) 
  AS 'ES Created TheoWPU'
FROM Prime.dbo.PivotData
```